# Boot Linux (Debian) from a USB Drive with GRUB

Tags: linux, debian, boot, grub, usb-drive

I would like to install Debian on a USB drive and boot it from there. I have a USB drive with 64 GB of diskspace.

So I installed Debian Jessie (non-free) on it, and installed GRUB on the USB drive itself. Now I choose to boot from that drive, but it doesn't boot. The computer starts and I just get a text cursor blinking whenever I try to boot from it.

What else should one do to make such a USB bootable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing grub manually from another linux. After installing Debian on the USB drive, mount it to `/mnt` and then use the command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdb --force --boot-directory=/mnt
```

assuming that the device of the USB drive name is `/dev/sdb` (DON'T SUFFIX THIS WITH NUMBERS SUCH AS sdb1). You can know the device name using `fdisk -l` (run it only as root).

Note: As I was doing this with many other things I'm not sure whether it's `boot-directory` or `root-directory`. Please edit the question if you know the answer.