# Debian Gnu/Linux on SSD in ThinkPad T-43 Ultra Bay will not Boot

Tags: debian, boot, grub2, thinkpad

I am trying to get a few more useful years from a ThinkPad T-43 (x86 processor, model 1871-48U, BIOS 1.29, which, [according to this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade_Downloads) appears to be the latest.) by installing Debian Buster i386.  I want to put it on an SSD installed in the Ultra Bay, where the CD/DVD drive normally lives. I do not want or need dual-boot.  I can install Buster, but can't get it to boot.

A few possibly relevant facts:

- The main drive bay of the T-43 is equipped for a PATA device.
- Windows 7 *will* boot from SSD in the Ultra Bay, with or without a drive in the main bay.
- *Patience* is the key to installing to a drive in the Ultra Bay when there is no drive present in the main bay.  You just have to wait through the timeouts. <strike>For reasons I don't understand, it seems impossible to install anything on a drive in the Ultra Bay without a drive present in the main (PATA) bay.</strike>  I conjecture that has something to do with the internal PATA / SATA bridge making it "look like" there's a disk present, but that's just a guess.
- I *can* install Debian Buster (i386) on a magnetic disk PATA drive in the main drive bay.  It boots as expected, with no error messages and no grub prompt.

So, with a copy of Buster installed on the main PATA drive, I did another install from USB with the target being the SSD in the Ultra Bay.  I made the choice of "everything in one partition," so there's only a root partition and a swap partition.  I manually selected the SSD at the point in the process where grub is installed in the MBR.

That install would not boot.  I got a blank screen with flashing cursor and nothing else.

If I boot from the PATA drive, I can see the SSD as /dev/sdb.  I can mount the root (only) partition and see that the expected files are there.  It just won't boot.

Attempting to force a boot loader on the SSD I tried

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdb --force --boot-directory=/mnt` as suggested in [this answer.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203912/308953)

That got me a `grub>` prompt after boot from the SSD.  The response to `ls` was `(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (fd0)`.  (There is no floppy drive, but there is a floppy connector, and it's enabled in the BIOS.)

I entered the following grub parameters:

```
grub> set root=(hd0,1)
grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
grub> initrd /initrd.img
grub> boot
```

That actually got me to the Debian desktop after numerous errors of "ATA.1 device not ready" and "SRST failed errno -16."  (I believe that ATA.1 is the main bay, which was empty at the time.)

Once I reached the desktop and opened a terminal, the `update-grub` command (as root) appeared to work.

Sadly, a reboot brings me right back to the `grub>` prompt.

I tried `grub-install /dev/sda --force --boot-directory=/` after rebooting and entering the grub parameters above.  Rebooting still gets me a grub prompt.

I'm pretty sure at this point that I'm doing something wrong with grub.  Help on what I've been doing wrong will be most appreciated.

**Note:** In case others read this, someone in a ThinkPad forum commented offhand that *"older ThinkPads will not boot from USB 3 drives."*  I could have saved myself a lot of grief had I seen that a couple of days earlier.  I'd give credit if I remembered who posted that, but I don't.

Comment: What is your BIOS version?

Comment: @Mr.Donutz 1.29 (70ET69WW) 2007-05-29  According to [this](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/BIOS_Upgrade_Downloads) that appears to be current.

Comment: What is the model number? I've seen a number of different 4-digit models, some beginning with `1`, others with `2`. Does yours start with a `2`?

Comment: @Mr.Donutz Model 1871-48U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup, I was missing something about grub.  After booting through entering the grub parameters, one needs `update-grub` followed by `grub-install /dev/sda`  I'm not sure why doing it with `--force` didn't have the same effect.

It boots without intervention now, but still takes forever because it's timing out on the "phantom" disk in the main bay.  I think that's another question for another time.

Comment: Glad that worked. Funny enough, I think I've had a similar problem not too long ago, but totally forgot about the `update-grub` part now. Have you set the correct device first in the BIOS boot order? You might also have a play with the Config -> Serial ATA setting (AHCI or Compatibility).

Comment: @Mr.Donutz Thanks.  I do have the boot order correct.  I'll poke at the other stuff.  I'm going to use this machine as a testing device for web applications, so it won't get booted very often.